# Adding the connections between frontend jquery ajax and backend spring boot user does not work

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-boot, forms

I am trying to link my registration form to my backend but i get this error when trying.
I am using java spring boot and jquery ajax.

Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; For input string: "users"]

my users class

```
@Data
@Entity
//this will create Construct we don't need it but for learning



public class Users {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String role;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ShoppingBasket> shoppingBasket;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Orders> orders;
}
```

my users service

```
@Service
public class UsersService {

    private final UsersRepository userRepo;
    public UsersService(UsersRepository userRepo) {
        this.userRepo = userRepo;
    }
    public Users createUser(Users user) {
        return userRepo.save(user);
    }
    public List<Users> getAllUsers() {
        return userRepo.findAll();
    }
    public Users getUserById(Long id) {
        return userRepo.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User", "id", id));
    }
    public Users updateUser(Long id, Users userDetails) {
        Users user = userRepo.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User", "id", id));
        user.setFirstName(userDetails.getFirstName());
        user.setLastName(userDetails.getLastName());
        user.setRole(userDetails.getRole());
        return userRepo.save(user);
    }
    public void deleteUser(Long id) {
        Users user = userRepo.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User", "id", id));
        userRepo.delete(user);
    }
}
```

my users controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UsersController {

    @Autowired
    private UsersService usersService;

    @GetMapping
    public List<Users> getAllUsers() {
        return usersService.getAllUsers();
    }


    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Users getUserById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return usersService.getUserById(id);
    }


    @PostMapping
    public Users createUser(@RequestBody Users user) {

        return usersService.createUser(user);
    }



    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public Users updateUser(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Users user) {
        return usersService.updateUser(id, user);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void deleteUser(@PathVariable Long id) {
        usersService.deleteUser(id);
    }
}
```

and my Frontend

js

```
$("#signup-form").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var user = {
        name: $("#name").val(),
        email: $("#email").val(),
        password: $("#password").val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/users",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(user),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("User created successfully", data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.error("Error creating user", error);
        }
    });
});
```

Html

```
<div class="container mt-5">
  <h2>Registration Form</h2>
  <form action="http://localhost:8080/users/users">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email address:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="firstName">Firstname:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="lastName">Lastname:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

I expect when I click on the submit button that the user is saved in my backend. the database is connected and is working.